# Flask-SQLAlchemy One to Many relationship failed to locate a name

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask app with Flask-SQLAlchemy. I'm trying to make a one to many relationship from a user to a trip. I saw that, if I use the declarative_base of SQLAlchemy it works but when I use the db.Model from Flask-SQLAlchemy it dosen't work.

I'm getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|User|User, expression 'Trip' failed to locate a name ("name 'Trip' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'models.user.User'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

Here are the models:

database.py

```
from flask import abort 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from sqlalchemy import exc

db = SQLAlchemy()


class Mixin(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())
    date_changed = db.Column(
        db.DateTime, nullable=True, onupdate=db.func.now())
    date_to = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
```

user.py

```
from database import Mixin, db

class User(Mixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'User'        
    trips = db.relationship(
        'Trip',
        backref=db.backref('user', lazy='joined'),
        lazy='dynamic'
    )
```

trip.py

```
from database import Mixin, db

class Trip(Mixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Trip'
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)        
    user_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('User.id'),
        nullable=False
    )
```

Comment: You probably aren't importing the `trip` module at all, or if you are you are not doing it at the right time.

Comment: But why would it work if I use the declarative_base from SQLAlchemy ?

Comment: I don't know, you'll have to post the rest of your code.

Answer (score 25):

Storing all models in one file is a good idea, but only for a small number of models. For the large I would prefer to store models in semantically separate files.

```
models
├── __init__.py
├── model1.py
├── model2.py
└── model3.py
```

In the `__init__.py` need to import all models files

```
import models.model1.py
import models.model2.py
import models.model3.py
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me. I'd really appreciate if you could elaborate and tell why that solves the problem

Comment: You could also use `import models.model1` (without `.py` extension). This works in my machine, Python 3.9.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it by using one file for my models. I didn't have enough models to need multiple model files anyway.

Comment: That's a bad notion saying you have to have enough models for storing them in their own files. That's called clean code structure and has nothing to do with the number of models.